# Dropdown list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Required dropdown effect is not been created. Please help. Thanks in advance

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#navigation ul").mouseenter(
        function(){ $("#navigation li a").fadeIn(); 
    }); 
    $("#navigation ul").mouseleave(
        function(){ $("#navigation li ").fadeOut(); 
    }); 
});
```

### html

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.php">First</a>
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="index.php">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Second</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Read a bit on formatting your codes :)

Comment: Change this line `$("#navigation li ").fadeOut();` to `$("#navigation li a").fadeOut();`

Comment: I did tried that Morpheus.Didn't worked!

Comment: Well the first problem is that you're targeting an ID `#navigation` when in your code it's a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are trying to do. Try the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sHCjJ/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.php">First</a>
        <ul class="navigation_level2" style='display:none'>
            <li><a href="index.php">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Second</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(".navigation").mouseenter(
        function(){ $(".navigation_level2").fadeIn(); 
    }); 
    $(".navigation").mouseleave(
        function(){ $(".navigation_level2").fadeOut(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: That was bang on!Thanks Wolf!

Comment: Please close the question whenever you get the answer. Otherwise others will also waste time on that...

Answer (score 0):

your "navigation" is given as a class and you are accessing it as id ($("#navigation")). class can be accessed as $(".navigation"). try your code like this.

Comment: While this is definitely a problem, it does not solve the entire issue.

Comment: Yes...it doesnt solve the entire issue...Dropdown effect is still not working j08691

Comment: Well then this really isn't an answer is it?